# getline gets skipped on derived class constructor

Tags: c++, getline, istream

```
    Racecar::Racecar(istream& in) : Car(in) {
        vector<string> result{};
        string str{};
        while (getline(in, str, ',')) {
            str.erase(remove(str.begin(), str.end(), ' '), str.end());
            result.push_back(str);
        }
        m_booster = stod(result.back());
        
    }
```

```
    Car::Car(istream& is) {
        vector<string> result{};
        string str{};
        while (getline(is, str, ',')) {
            str.erase(remove(str.begin(), str.end(), ' '), str.end());
            result.push_back(str);
        }
        carMaker = result[1];
        if (!checkCondition(result[2][0])) {
            throw "EXCEPTION: not a valid condition.";
        }
        carCondition = result[2][0];
        if (!stod(result[3])) {
            throw "EXCEPTION: topspeed is not a number.";
        }
        carTopSpeed = stod(result[3]);
    }
```

Base class Car is called passing in the `istream& in`, I would like to have access to the values of `istream&` to extract the last "string" but getline get's skipped for some reason. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: In Racecar class the after the constructor is called, getline gets skipped without populating the results vector<string>

Comment: Car's constructor will only finish after all comma-delimited have been extracted from the input stream. Therefore, it is logically impossible for Racecar's constructor to find anything comma-delimited in the input stream because Car's constructor already read everything. The End.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Thank you so much for your comment, I understand what you said but is there workaround for this?

Comment: Sure: change Car's constructor to not extract all comma-delimited content from the input stream, leaving some for Racecar's. You need to follow The Golden Rule Of Computer Programming, which says "your computer always does exactly what you tell it to do instead of what you want it to do". All you have to do is tell your computer exactly what it needs to do in Car's constructor, so that Racecar's constructor will still find something in the input stream.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik You are totally right! I love you dude no homo <3

Comment: @HekmatHamidi I would probably make `result` be a `protected` member of `Car` that `Racecar` can access. Let `Car`do all the reading, then `Racecar can simple use the result as needed.